# Fuzzy string match comparing two large files using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, large-files, fuzzy-comparison

I have two large files, File1 and File2,each containing the names of companies.  I am trying to find a fuzzy match of companies names ("companyname") from File2 to match to File1. Currently, I am not able to complete processing since it is timing out. Is there a more efficient way to improve the speed of processing?

Here is my my code:

```
File1=pd.read_csv("directory/File1.csv")
File2=pd.read_csv("directory/File2.csv")

def match_name(name, list_names, min_score=0):
    # -1 score in case we don't get any matches
    max_score = -1
    # Returning empty name for no match as well
    max_name = ""
    # Iternating over all names in the other
    for name2 in list_names:
        #Finding fuzzy match score
        score = fuzz.ratio(name, name2)
        # Checking if we are above our threshold and have a better score
         if (score > min_score) & (score > max_score):
            max_name = name2
            max_score = score
    return (max_name, max_score)


dict_list = []

for name in File2.companyname:
    # Use our method to find best match, we can set a threshold here
    match = match_name(File1.companyname, File2.companyname, 70)

    # New dict for storing data
    dict_ = {}
    dict_.update({"companyname" : name})
    dict_.update({"match_companyname" : match[0]})
    dict_.update({"score" : match[1]})
    dict_list.append(dict_)
merge_table = pd.DataFrame(dict_list)

# Save results
merge_table.to_csv("directory/Saved.csv")
```

Comment: What do you mean it's timing out? I understand you thinking it's taking too long, but  what limits the time you can let this code run for?

Comment: Additionally, what library are you using for the fuzzy matching? I think I know but that's also important context for the question, probably more important than the fact that you're using pandas.

Comment: I am using fuzzywuzzy. It is basically taking too long and I have not one completed process after allowing the code to run for 24 hours.